# Download private files in s3bucket from drupal8 webforms

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I am using `webforms` module for career form in my `drupal8` website and the resume files are uploaded to s3 bucket as private.

Is there any way to download the resume from backend(admin)?

It was able to download the attachment file (resumes in s3 bucket) from backend using the default download section of `webform` module, when they have public access.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webform views (page or block) and take the file uploaded field. It will open/download the file automatically either public or private (path - system/files/S3filename).